# "Base for a neighborhood system at a point" vs. "base at a point"

Tags: general-topology, terminology

For a topological space X do the terms "base for a neighbourhood system at a point" and "base at a point" have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Usually these two things mean the same.